# Using IComparable interface to sort Products coming back from Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My items back from the repository like this:

---

**Lily's Kitchen Curious Kitten**

Wet Food

$10.00

**Peacock Feather Cat Toy**

Dry Food

$8.96

**Eden Country Cuisine Wet Cat Food Cans**

Toys

$2.3

I tried to implement the "IComparable interface" in my model called"Product" :

```
namespace GloriaPetShop.Models
{
public class Product:IComparable<Product>
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public float Weight { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Product other)
    {
        return Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
    }
}
}
```

then in my view page which is called "List.cshtml" I converted the model to the array and used sort method:

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>
@{
Array.Sort(Model.ToArray());
}
@foreach (var p in Model.ToArray())
{
<div>
    <h3>@p.Name</h3>
    @p.Category
    <h4>@p.Price.ToString("C")</h4>
</div>
}
```

but it still is not sorted alphabitacally like :

**Eden Country Cuisine Wet Cat Food Cans**

Wet Food

$10.00

**Lily's Kitchen Curious Kitten**

Dry Food

$8.96

**Peacock Feather Cat Toy**

Toys

$2.37

I know there may be a thousand ways to do it but I'm wondering how we can do it with IComparable interface?

Comment: You should do `var sortedColl = Model.OrderBy(x => x.Name);` and then use `sortedColl` in foreach loop. `foreach (var p in sortedColl)`. When you use OrderBy LINQ method you don't need to implement `IComparable`

Comment: Thanks, very nice . can I ask which book did you read that explain these stuff?

Comment: It's about learning the features of .Net and c# and experience. Google is the best friend.

Comment: thanks again, you are very good at c#